# train without having target column

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I have data from a year (many years but let's say one year for clarity).

Data has columns like Temperature, Humidity etc.

I want to train a model from October to March, in order to see if from April-July certain conditions are met (which were created from Oct-March) that imply a creation of disease for example. So, the target is 1 or 0.

So, the problem is that I must train a model from Oct-March without having a target column and I must predict the target column from April.

I can't think a way to make that work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a large conceptual problem.

If each row in the Oct-Mar dataset has data but no target, there is no possibility to train anything. There is no outcome linked to the predictors. You need one specific outcome for each row in the Oct-Mar dataset.

If I understand you correctly, you wish to construct a causal chain of the form (Oct-Mar)->(???)->(Apr-Sep)->Outcome. If this is the case, you can't train just on the Oct-Mar data.

There are different ways you can get at (???):

- You can go forward and use an unsupervised technique (e.g. k-means clustering) to distinguish patterns in the (Oct-Mar) data. You can then use the resulting classes as a substitute for the (???) target and try to predict it using the (Apr-Sep) data.
- You can even go backward and induce (???) using unsupervised ML from the (Apr-Sep) data and try to predict it with (Oct-Mar).
- You can come from both ways and cluster both datasets. Then you can check whether these clusters have anything to do with each other.

A different possibility would be to just link the (Oct-Mar) data to the corresponding (i.e. following) (Apr-Sep) data, so you get one dataset with just one target.